# Having problems building OpenCV 2.0 on CentOS 5?

Tags: opencv, centos5

I'd been trying to install OpenCV library to my centos system however when i type make and hit enter after configuring with cmake, i get the following error:

```
[100%] Building CXX object tests/cv/CMakeFiles/cvtest.dir/src/amoments.o
[100%] Building CXX object tests/cv/CMakeFiles/cvtest.dir/src/affine3d_estimator.o
[100%] Building CXX object tests/cv/CMakeFiles/cvtest.dir/src/acontours.o
[100%] Building CXX object tests/cv/CMakeFiles/cvtest.dir/src/areprojectImageTo3D.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/cvtest
CMakeFiles/cvtest.dir/src/highguitest.o: In function `CV_HighGuiTest::run(int)':
highguitest.cpp:(.text._ZN14CV_HighGuiTest3runEi+0x15): warning: the use of `tmpnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
[100%] Built target cvtest
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

and interesting, once i got this error:

```
[ 99%] Built target mltest
[ 99%] Generating generated0.i
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/proje/OpenCV-2.1.0/interfaces/python/gen.py", line 43, in ?
    if True in has_init and not all(has_init[has_init.index(True):]):
NameError: name 'all' is not defined
make[2]: *** [interfaces/python/generated0.i] Error 1
make[1]: *** [interfaces/python/CMakeFiles/cvpy.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What possibly is the cause of these errors? I need to install opencv immediately on this computer.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem.. It's the Python Interface...
By Default, Python 2.4 is installed on CentOS, and ot's not easy to upgrade to >2.6.

When OpenCV builds, it is confused by the Python version...

So I've disable the Python interface on "cmake" and it was OK.

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=NO ..

But, of course you can not use OpenCV with Python anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The Python function `all()` was introduced with version 2.5.  You are probably compiling with a version where `all()` does not exist in the Python language yet.

According to the Python [Built-in Functions List](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html), `all()` is equivalent to:

```
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

You may also need to define `any()`.  It is the equivalent of:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

More than likely though, if the setup script requires Python 2.5, so will the rest of the Python wrapper.